# What are the advantages or disadvantages of having multiple output nodes compared to a few within a neural network

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network

Are there any advantages or disadvantages of having many output nodes in a neural network compared to having a few?

For example if a scenario could be represented with 10, 3, 2 or 1 output nodes, which is considered better? - obviously it depends how you want to represent the outputs but say that doesn't matter for now.

Or does the number of output nodes not make a difference to the accuracy of the network, just the computational time needed to train it?

Comment: Don' you mean hidden nodes? Otherwise it depends on what you want your output to be. If you want your ANN to output R,G,B I would use 3 nodes and not 1.

Comment: I do mean output nodes. Say for example the network output numbers. It could either have one node to output 1, 3 or 5 etc. or i could have three nodes outputting the same data in binary e.g. 001, 011, 101 etc. Obviously this is a very basic example, I was just wondering about how the number of output nodes would affect the accuracy of the network...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of output nodes should match the number of values you want to compute. For simple regression or binary classification, you need only one output node. For [multiclass classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification) or [multiple regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression#Simple_and_multiple_regression), you need multiple output nodes.

In particular, binary classification using a feedforward neural net is done by computing the activation of a single output node, then checking whether it is larger than some threshold (commonly 0 or .5). For multiclass classification with *k* classes, you compute the values of *k* output nodes, then select the index *i* of the largest value to predict class *i*.

Also, with multiple output nodes you can do [multilabel classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification), where you again have a single output node per class/label and predict "true" for all nodes exceeding the threshold. Multilabel classification with *k* classes can also be performed by *k* binary classifiers, but you'd need to train all of those separately, which can be time-consuming with neural networks.